# How do I pass Anti Forgery Token when doing CRUD items from jTable to MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

When doing CRUD calls from jTable to my MVC5 controller how do I pass along the AntiForgeryToken? In order to get the action to complete I have to comment out the ValidateAntiForgeryToken portion which seems rather unsafe. If not then I get a "An error occured while communicating with the server." message.

jTable code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    //Prepare jtable plugin
    $('#CandidateTable').jtable({
        title: 'Candidates',
        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("List")',
            deleteAction: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
            updateAction: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
            createAction: '@Url.Action("Create")'
        },
        fields: {
            ID: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            FirstName: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)',
                width: '15%'
            },
            MiddleName: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)',
                width: '15%'
            },
            LastName: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)',
                width: '15%'
            },
            AnonymousID: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnonymousID)',
                width: '15%'
            },
            Email: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)',
                width: '15%'
            },
            GUID: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GUID)',
                width: '15%',
                create: false,
                edit: false
            }
        }
    });

    //Load person list from server
    $('#CandidateTable').jtable('load');
});
```

ASP.NET MVC 5 Create Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Create([Bind(Include = "FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,AnonymousID,Email")] Candidate candidate)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                candidate.GUID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
                candidate.IsActive = true;
                candidate.DateAdded = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
                candidate.DateModified = null;
                db.Candidates.Add(candidate);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Record = candidate });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Form is not valid! Please correct it and try again.");
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }            
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I figured it out. I needed to add an arbitrary field (**AFT**) and then add a custom input which @HTML.AntiForgeryToken outputs. Now i just need to figure out how to do this on Deletes since Delete only passes the primary key (id)

```
  $('#CandidateTable').jtable({
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 15,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'LastName ASC',
        title: 'Candidates',
        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("List")',
            deleteAction: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
            updateAction: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
            createAction: '@Url.Action("Create")'
        },
        fields: {
            ID: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            FirstName: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)',
                width: '15%'
            },
            MiddleName: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)',
                width: '15%'
            },
            LastName: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)',
                width: '15%'
            },
            AnonymousID: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnonymousID)',
                width: '15%'
            },
            Email: {
                title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)',
                width: '15%'
            },                
            __AFT__: {
                create: true,
                edit: true,
                list: false,
                input: function (data) {
                    return '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: The solution I use is typically adding a custom header to the request with the value of the anti forgery token, and then check it on the server. I'm unsure how to do this with jTable, however. If you want some guidance with a straight up AJAX example, let me know.

Comment: Oh very cool approach. My way did feel a bit "hacky." Thank you!

Comment: @kcabrams : please add update as an answer, worked for me

Comment: but yes, it did not work on delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is add a function to your `View` that will generate your anti-forgery token:

```
@functions{
    public string TokenHeaderValue()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
    }
}
```

The `@functions` block lets you add functions to your `Views`. They're useful in keeping all your functions in one spot which helps with organization.

Then, in your Javascript you would make an AJAX call and add the token as a `RequestVerificationToken` header:

```
$.ajax("api/values", {
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {  }, // JSON data goes here
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()' //Can be named whatever
    }
});
```

Now create the following utility method in your solution:

```
void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string cookieToken = "";
    string formToken = "";

    IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
    if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestVerificationToken", out tokenHeaders))
    {
        string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
        if (tokens.Length == 2)
        {
            cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
            formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
        }
    }
    AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
```

And call it like:

```
try{
   Utils.ValidateRequestHeader(request);
}
catch(HttpAntiForgeryException exc){
   //VALIDATION FAILED! RELEASE THE HOUNDS
}
```

ref: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to add this AntiForgeryToken to delete action of jTable. You have added `__AFT__` to the create and update actions correctly, no need to add headers and fetching in controller. For adding it to delete action you can write custom delete as below. Updated your code

```
var tokenId = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';

$('#CandidateTable').jtable({
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 15,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'LastName ASC',
    title: 'Candidates',
    actions: {
        listAction: '@Url.Action("List")',
        deleteAction: function (postData) {
            postData.__RequestVerificationToken = $(tokenId).val();
            return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: postData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $dfd.resolve(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $dfd.reject();
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        updateAction: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
        createAction: '@Url.Action("Create")'
    },
    fields: {
        ID: {
            key: true,
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: false
        },
        FirstName: {
            title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)',
            width: '15%'
        },
        MiddleName: {
            title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)',
            width: '15%'
        },
        LastName: {
            title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)',
            width: '15%'
        },
        AnonymousID: {
            title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnonymousID)',
            width: '15%'
        },
        Email: {
            title: '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)',
            width: '15%'
        },                
        __AFT__: {
            create: true,
            edit: true,
            list: false,
            input: function (data) {
                return tokenId;
            }
        }

    }
```

I have tested and tried this myself. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this code lying around, maybe it will help you. I'm guessing jtable uses $.ajax for it's requests so I guess it should work.

```
// Setup CSRF safety for AJAX:
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (options.type.toUpperCase() === "POST") {
        // We need to add the verificationToken to all POSTs
        var token = $("input[name^=__RequestVerificationToken]").eq(0);
        var headers = {};
        headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = token.val();
        if (!token.length) return;

        var tokenName = token.attr("name");

        // If the data is JSON, then we need to put the token in the QueryString:
        if (options.contentType.indexOf('application/json') === 0) {
           // Add the token to the URL, because we can't add it to the JSON data:
           options.headers = headers;
        } 
   }
});
```